# Error with Gdal 1.10 install on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: qgis, postgis, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

I've installed GDAL 1.9 then upgrade to 1.10 on Ubuntu 13.10 and then now it's error (gdalwarp can work but gdal_translate is fail)

gdal_translate
ERROR 1: gdal_translate was compiled against GDAL 1.9 but current library version is 1.10

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend removing the old GDAL completely.

As an alternative, just remove the binaries that cause problems (probably from `/usr/local/bin` with something like `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/gdal_translate`.

If you need to use both versions, you can probably set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to select particular library variants and use explicit paths to the binary you want. That is a bit off-topic for gis.SE though, and a google search will probably help you find something like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables as much as I can.